# Merging sublists that contain common elements

Tags: python

I am trying to code a fast function which will loop through the elements in the sublists and merge the sublists if they contain element. For example, the list `[[0, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` should be merged to `[[0, 3, 4], [5, 6]].` The sublists can be of any size and each sublist can have a different size, therefore could contain many elements.

My code so far (which does not work) is shown below. The error that comes up is: `slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`

```
def join_clusters(clusters):
    for cluster in clusters:
        for j in cluster:
            for k in clusters[cluster:]:
                for h in k:
                    if j == h:
                        cluster.append(k)
                        clusters.pop(k)
                        return clusters
```

Comment: Do you only want to merge adjacent sublists? Would `[[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7]]` get merged to `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]`?

Comment: @PM2Ring I assume so, that's the way I've done it

Comment: I think you're trying to solve a set consolidation/connected components/union-find problem -- in which case it's a duplicate of many previous questions -- but your example is a little confusing because it could be interpreted as linking neighbouring chains.  Should `[[1,2],[3,1],[1,3]]` become `[[1,2,3]]`?

Comment: yes, that is what I am needing. [[1,2],[3,1],[1,3]] would become [[1,2,3]]

Answer (score 2):

If the subsets are sorted I would just try to do something with sets.

```
from itertools import islice

def merge(T):
  idx = 0
  result = [set(T[0])]
  for sublst in islice(T, 1, len(T)):
    subset = set(sublst)
    if result[idx] & subset:
      result[idx].update(subset)
    else:
      result.append(set(sublst))
      idx += 1
  return [sorted(sub) for sub in result]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used a while loop to make it easier to reference the next cluster in the list

```
def join_clusters(clusters):
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(clusters) - 1:
        for element in clusters[idx]:
            if element in clusters[idx + 1]:
                clusters[idx].remove(element)
                clusters[idx] = clusters[idx] + clusters[idx + 1]                
                del(clusters[idx + 1])
                break
        idx = idx + 1
    return clusters
```

hope this helps you :)

Comment: My mistake, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I need!

Comment: @Hello No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which works for any kind of sublist, regardless of whether it's sorted:

```
def join_clusters(clusters):
    result = clusters[:1]                          #1
    for cluster in clusters[1:]:
        if cluster[0] == result[-1][-1]:
            result[-1] = result[-1] + cluster[1:]  #2
        else:
            result.append(cluster)                 #3
    return result
```

Examples:

```
>>> c1 = [[0, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> join_clusters(c1)
[[0, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

```
>>> c2 = [[3, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [1, 3], [3, 1], [1, 2]]
>>> join_clusters(c2)
[[3, 1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1, 3, 1, 2]]
```

```
>>> les_mis = "At the end of the day you're another day older".split()
>>> join_clusters(les_mis)
['Athend', 'of', 'the', "dayou're", 'another', 'day', 'older']
```

Notes:

`#1`: Use `result = clusters[:1][:]` if you want the output to contain only copies of the input, rather than the actual original sublists.

`#2`: `result[-1] += cluster[1:]` is not used, as it would mutate elements of the original list, which may be undesirable.

`#3`: Use `result.append(cluster[:])` if you want the output to contain only copies of the input, rather than the actual original sublists.

Comment: Would there be any way to delete the duplicates, so that [2, 1, 3, 1, 2] became [1,2,3] (order is not important)

Comment: Also, would there be any way to alter the list clusters, rather than create a copy?

Comment: 1. Not without starting from scratch - it looks like the question I thought you were asking is not the one you wanted an answer to. 2. Well, yes, but given #1 there doesn't seem much point ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help.